# completeness, negligble sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E, \mathcal E, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\mathcal N$ be the collection of all negligible subsets of $E$. Let $\mathcal F$ be the collection of all sets having the form $A \cup N$ with $A \in \mathcal E$ and $N \in \mathcal N$. Show that $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$.

For additivity, let's say $(B_n) \in \mathcal F$. Then, $B_n = A_n \cup N_n$ for each $n$. We know $\bigcup_n A_n \in \mathcal E$. There exists $M_n \in \mathcal E$ such that $N_n \subset M_n$ and $\mu(M_n) = 0$ by definition of a negligible set. Thus, by Boole's inequality, $\bigcup N_n \in \mathcal N$. I am a bit struggling with complementality. Let $B \in \mathcal F$. Then, $B = A \cup N$. We know $E - A \in \mathcal E$, but what do we know things about $E - N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M\in\mathcal{E}$ with $N\subseteq M$ and $\mu\left(M\right)=0$.

Then $B=A\cup M\in\mathcal{E}$ hence $\mathcal{E}\ni B^{c}=A^c\cap M^c\subseteq A^{c}\cap N^{c}$.

This with $N'=\left(A^{c}\cap N^{c}\right)-B^{c}\subseteq M$.

So we can write $\left(A\cup N\right)^{c}=A^{c}\cap N^{c}=B^{c}\cup N'$
where $N'\subseteq M$.